# Try to run metatrader 4 with wine emulator in Centos

Tags: centos7, wine, metatrader4

I tried to run the applications metatrader 4 ,notepad++ with the wine emulator in Centos 7. I have Wine 8 installed and also Mono and Gecko.  it crashes with error "virtual_setup_exception". The explorer.exe works very well.Any ideas?

[giannis@estert ~]$ wine64 mt4setup.exe
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
007c:fixme:hid:handle_IRP_MN_QUERY_ID Unhandled type 00000005
00d0:err:environ:init_peb starting L"Z:\home\giannis\mt4setup.exe" in experimental wow64 mode
00d0:err:module:load_wow64_ntdll failed to load L"\??\C:\windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll" error c0000135
00d0:err:virtual:virtual_setup_exception stack overflow 1808 bytes addr 0x7f9b188919a2 stack 0x7508f0 (0x750000-0x751000-0x84fd20)
[giannis@estert ~]$

Comment: The call is wine64 mt4setup.exe

Comment: I have rebuilt Wine and i have the error message .

0024:err:vulkan:get_vulkan_driver Wine was built without Vulkan support.
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X connection to 185.216.203.101:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).